How to resolve error so as to be able to publish to Play Store? Will these errors prevent me from doing so?
I'm getting the following error while building my Flutter project for Android. This is happening for the dependency google_mobile_ads that my project uses.
Note: /home/myName/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_mobile_ads-5.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemobileads/FlutterRequestAgentProvider.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I tried to compile with:
flutter build apk --release --dart-options=-Xlint:deprecation

and with:
flutter build apk --release -Xlint:deprecation

And in both commands I'm getting errors saying --dart-options and -X options does not exist. I am unable to further information on why the error is occuring.
I am planning to publish my project to Google Play Store. So, I'm curious about if I will be able to publish my Android app with this error and also the error mentioned in my previous question?

From my experience "...overrides a  deprecated API" message is just a warning. It means the package/plugin uses some native deprecated methods. So no, it doesn't prevent the apps from being deployed.
